# Separating Multiple Strings in Paste() with Newline

Tags: r, string

I have a bunch of strings, like

```
x <- "hello"
y <- "world"
z <- "!'
```

And I want the output to be

```
"hello"
"world"
"!"
```

I thought what I was supposed to do was use `sep = "\n"` in `paste()`, i.e. `paste(x, y, z, sep = "\n")`. But this doesn't seem to be quite working, as it just puts the strings into 1 paragraph, like "hello world !". What am I doing wrong with `paste()`? What should the correct code be? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
paste(c(x, y, z), collapse = "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The way `paste` has been called by `OP` it should have collapsed `x`, `y` and `z` as per expectation.

```
paste(x, y, z, sep = "\n")
#[1] "hello\nworld\n!"
```

Notice that `\n` is not converted in `new-line`. The reason is that `\n` works with `cat`.

To see the result in multi-line `cat` should have used. The `cat` transform `\n` in new line.

```
cat(paste(x, y, z, sep = "\n"))
#hello
#world
#!
```

Another option could be to use just `cat`

```
cat(x, y, z, sep = "\n")
#hello
#world
#!
```

OR

```
cat(c(x, y, z), sep = "\n")
#hello
#world
#!
```

OR

```
cat(sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s", x,y,z))
#hello
#world
#!
```